# import index XAO price into google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm trying to load the asx all ords (INDEXASX: XAO) price into a Google sheet cell. Most stocks return a result like BHP below, but cannot get an index like XAO to work.

`=googlefinance("asx:bhp", "price")`  This works for BHP.

`=googlefinance("INDEXASX: XAO", "price")`  This doesn't work for XAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=googlefinance("indexasx:XAO")
```

works for me.